# NSURLSession : Load data in a Table View is not working

Tags: json, tableview, block, nsurlsession

Hi I am using NSURLSession to fetch data from a server and I am using the following code for that purpose.

```
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:urlForDiseaseTypes completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error)

      {
          if(!error)
          {
              NSHTTPURLResponse *httpRespc = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
              if(httpRespc.statusCode == 200)
              {
                  NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                      diseaseArray = [result valueForKeyPath:@"Value"];
                      diseaseIDarray = [result valueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                  [self.tableViewMain reloadData];
                  });
              }
          }
      }]resume];
```

And I am getting value inside both arrays(diseaseArray,diseaseIDarray). diseaseArray values are supposed to get displayed on table view. But when tableview opens no values are getting visible. When checked inside in Table View methods the array count is zero. How can I load my tableview with the values I get from NSURLSession block.

Currently I am calling this function in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Where should I call the method that contains the block? in viewDidLoad or in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Sorry guys. Method is right. Due to hidden property tableView was not visible.Now working fine